# Upload a .csv file to metabase

Tags: database, csv, metabase

I would like to upload a .csv file to metabase but it doesn't offer the option.

What would be the easiest way to get it done? Spin up a DB locally?
Or is there a plugin that can be added?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a 3rd-party driver created for this purpose already: https://github.com/Markenson/csv-metabase-driver

Answer (score 1):

Metabase does not provide an option to upload .csv file. The easiest way to do this would be install a database like MySQL locally where you can import an csv directly and connect to that database.

Comment: Although Metabase doesn't provide a native option to upload a CSV, you can add a plugin to read csv file. Please check metabase plugins site at https://www.metabase.com/docs/latest/developers-guide-drivers.html. You'll need download plugin .jar file and put It on /plugins directory of your metabase installation.

Answer (score 0):

For online tools with a free trial, you can try [Acho](https://acho.io/). It supports exporting .csv files to Metabase. I think it's pretty easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to upload a .csv file to metabase but it doesn't offer the option.

Little bit late to this, but [Metabase does offer csv upload now](https://www.metabase.com/product/csv-uploads)!